# Laravel 9 - Переменная в ошибке @error blade

Tags: laravel

Доброе время суток, помогите решить проблему
Создал FormRequest для проверки валидации формы
В форме есть массив localization (поля на разных языках)

Проверка формы

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
      'localization' => 'array',
      'localization.*' => 'array',
      'localization.*.name_1' => 'required',
      'localization.*.name_2' => 'required',
      'localization.*.name_3' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Хочу вывести ошибку под собственно полем

использую переменную языка в цикле для получения его id

```
@error('localization.{{ $language->id }}.name_3')
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {{ $message }}
   </div>
@enderror
```

и ничего не работает( Если вручную вписать @error('localization.31.name_3'), то все отображается а вот с переменной {{ $language->id }} в цикле не хочет..

Что делаю не правильно, очень прошу помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что шаблонизация внутри директив не работает. В них применяется PHP. Ваша строка `localization.{{ $language->id }}.name_3` ровно это и означает без замены.

Вам надо склеить строку, как это делается в PHP:

```
@error('localization.' . $language->id . '.name_3')
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {{ $message }}
   </div>
@enderror
```

Comment: Можно [чуть удобнее](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) подставить значение: `"localization.${language->id}.name_3"`

Comment: @nomnoms12 Тоже вариант. Любая конкатенация из PHP подойдет